# Jenkins is unable to connect to GitLab

Tags: ssh, git, jenkins, gitlab

I've got Jenkins and GitLab setup in my homelab running in docker containers. I was able to connect to GitLab from Jenkins, pull the desired repo, and perform the steps in the Jenkinsfile. I had a power outage that brought down the lab recently. Since bringing everything back up, Jenkins is no longer able to connect to GitLab.

In Jenkins, the build fails with the following

```
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@gitlab:homelab/bind9.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
git@gitlab: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

In an effort to troubleshoot, I connected to the Jenkins agent container and tried to clone the repo and get prompted for a password, implying the SSH key is not being accepted/used. So I tried using SSH to connect with the git user directly, and also get a prompt for password there. Using -vvv with SSH shows that the public key is being passed, but the receive packet is type 51.

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:xxx
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@gitlab's password:
```

From previous issues with SSH the receive packet of 51 led to a discovery of permission issues with one of the files/directories involved in the exchange. I checked the Jenkins agent .ssh directory and made sure it was 0700. The files in the directory are all 0600. On the GitLab side, the git user home directory is /var/opt/gitlab. I confirmed the .ssh directory there is 0700, and the files are all 0600.

I created a second SSH key and added it to the repository in GitLab. Then changed the configuration in Jenkins to use that new key, and got the same error. When trying to connect to GitLab with SSH on the Jenkins agent directly using the new key, I get the same receive packet 51 and resulting password prompt.

Final note, this key works on a separate system in the lab. There I'm able to connect and push changes to the repo without any problem. This leads me to believe the problem is not the key, nor on the GitLab side. Leaving it to be something on the Jenkins side at fault.

Comment: Have you checked the SSH server's logs (preferably at `DEBUG` level)? That's where the accept/reject decisions happen, after all.

Comment: I had watched the logs for the GitLab server. One thing I didn't do was check the logs on the host running the GitLab container. Watching those logs revealed that Jenkins is hitting the host SSH port instead of the GitLab port. I now remember that the GitLab container has port 22 mapped to an alternate port. So I need to figure out how to get Jenkins to use this alternate port instead of the standard port 22. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For those in the future who may run into a similar situation.

As stated in the question and comment, I was observing the ssh logs on the gitlab container during initial troubleshooting, but forgot about the host itself. Observing the ssh logs on the host revealed an invalid user attempt from the jenkins agent connection. This meant that the agent was not hitting the gitlab container's ssh server. This was because the container had ssh mapped to an alternate port.

The way I fixed the issue was by adding a `.ssh/config` file in the Jenkins agent container in the jenkins user's directory. Inside the `.ssh/config` I added the alternate port that GitLab container was listening on.

So I ended up with the following

```
Host gitlab
    Port xxxx
```

Enter the port value needed/desired. Once that was in place, Jenkins was able to checkout the repository and perform the build.